# exif_imagetype is not working in windows

Tags: php, image-uploading, exif

I am developing app using cakephp 2.4 in windows in which I need to create Image upload facility. But when I use `exif_imagetype` it gives me fatal-error. So using this code I checked if exif tool is installed or not

```
if (function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
echo "This function is installed";
} else {
echo "It is not";
}
```

And its showing that exif tool is not installed. But in `php.ini` I can see this part

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
```

I am not sure what is wrong. Can anybody help me to solve this. 
My php version is **5.4.3** and I am using `wampserver`

Comment: php_exif.dll is commented out in the INI you show (the leading `;`).

Comment: I figured it out. But thnx @Pekka웃 for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXIF` extension is a standard part of PHP distributions, but it must be enabled in php.ini file in order to use its functions. On windows, `EXIF` extension also depends on mbstring, an extension that provides multi-byte string parsing. Moreover, the sequence of enabling extensions in php.ini file does matter. If exif is enabled prior to mbstring, `EXIF` functions will not be available at run-time.

## mbstring extension must be enabled before EXIF!

which is enabled in your case but `php_exif.dll` is not.

If you need to use `EXIF` functions in your environment, be it development or production, this is something you need to keep in mind. By default, extensions are ordered in alphabetical order in php.ini file. This makes it very easy to run into situation when you start banging your head against the wall as you don’t realize why `function_exists('exif_imagetype')` keeps returning FALSE even though you have enabled both EXIF and mbstring extensions.

Remove the comment `;` and enable `EXIF` function

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon (;)

Before:

```
;extension=php_exif.dll
```

After:

```
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Save the php.ini and then restart wampserver